# Email notifications aren't sent from WordPress

Tags: email, wordpress, mail-notification

I have deployed a WordPress site in a Ubuntu 14.04 server. The problem is that the email notifications from the site aren't sent. I checked the firewall is inactive.

The port 25 is open, but the ports 465, 587 are closed. Unfortunately I don't have the ability for the moment to open these ports. Is there a way to use the port 25 to send the emails ? Or the problem is located somewhere else?

Comment: What you use for smtp server? `localhost` or ? If you use `localhost`, do you have installed `postfix` or `sendmail` on you server? You do not need open port, except 25 in situation if you use `localhost` for `smtp`. If your mail server is far end `smtp` server, can you `telnet` on server on port `25`?